# cannot populate tableview with just the name

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to populate my tableview with just the name of the Categories. When I populate the tableview it shows this...

```
Category(name: "Sandwiches & Burgers", items: [])
```

Heres where I append all of my information...

```
 let sortedKeys = newArray.sorted{$0.0 < $1.0}
    let shake = Item(name: "Shake", carbs: 20)
    let fries = Item(name: "Fries", carbs: 30)

    let beverages = Category(name: "Beverages", items: [shake])
    let chips_fries = Category(name: "Chips & Fries", items: [fries])
    let desserts = Category(name: "Desserts", items: [])
    let other = Category(name: "Other Menu Items", items: [])
    let sandwiches_burgers = Category(name: "Sandwiches & Burgers", items: [])
    let sides = Category(name: "Sides", items: [])

    a_w = Restaurant(name: "A&W", categories: [beverages, chips_fries, desserts, other, sandwiches_burgers, sides])

    menuArray = [a_w]
```

and then my class

```
struct Item {
let name: String
let carbs: Int
}
struct Category {
    let name: String
    let items: [Item]
}

struct Restaurant {
    let name: String
    let categories: [Category]

}
```

Here's where I populate...

```
var currentRestaurant:Restaurant!
var menuArray:[Restaurant] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var array = currentRestaurant.categories
    print(array)
    let currentCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
    currentCell.textLabel?.text = String(describing: array[indexPath.item])
    return currentCell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return currentRestaurant.categories.count
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your data source `cellForRowAt` is supposed to be:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let category = currentRestaurant.categories[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = category.name
    return cell
}
```

But at some point before reloading the table view you have to set `currentRestaurant` to `menuArray[0]`

---

Actually the usual way to handle this kind of data source is to displays the restaurants in sections.

Please declare the data source array to some more descriptive name than `menuArray`

```
var restaurants = [Restaurant]()
```

Then return the number of restaurants in numberOfSections

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return restaurants.count
}
```

and the number of categories in `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let restaurant = restaurants[section]
    return restaurant.categories.count
}
```

and `cellForRow` is

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    let restaurant = restaurants[indexPath.section]
    let category = restaurant.categories[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = category.name
    return cell
}
```

With this way you don't need `currentRestaurant` at all.

In `viewDidLoad` populate the data source array and reload the table view

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let shake = Item(name: "Shake", carbs: 20)
    let fries = Item(name: "Fries", carbs: 30)

    let beverages = Category(name: "Beverages", items: [shake])
    let chips_fries = Category(name: "Chips & Fries", items: [fries])
    let desserts = Category(name: "Desserts", items: [])
    let other = Category(name: "Other Menu Items", items: [])
    let sandwiches_burgers = Category(name: "Sandwiches & Burgers", items: [])
    let sides = Category(name: "Sides", items: [])

    restaurants = [Restaurant(name: "A&W", categories: [beverages, chips_fries, desserts, other, sandwiches_burgers, sides])]

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Nothing shows up in the tableview when I do this. Do I need to reload data at some point. @vadian

Comment: Of course. Actually the code to populate the data source is supposed to be in `viewDidLoad()`. At the end call `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: Can you please edit your answer so I can see it more clearly @vadian

Comment: Im working with a tableview controller not a tableview outlet btw @vadian