# tableview populating same string

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to populate my tableview with an array of a custom struct, currently it will only populate the table view of each section with the same array.

Heres where I append...

```
    let shake = Item(name: "Shake", carbs: 20)
    let fries = Item(name: "Fries", carbs: 30)
    let pie = Item(name: "Pie", carbs: 23)

    let beverages = Category(name: "Beverages", items: [shake])
    let chips_fries = Category(name: "Chips & Fries", items: [fries])
    let desserts = Category(name: "Desserts", items: [pie])
    let other = Category(name: "Other Menu Items", items: [])
    let sandwiches_burgers = Category(name: "Sandwiches & Burgers", items: [])
    let sides = Category(name: "Sides", items: [])

    a_w = Restaurant(name: "A&W", categories: [beverages, chips_fries, desserts, other, sandwiches_burgers, sides])

    restaurants = [a_w]
```

Here's where I try to populate the table view with the array of Items...

```
   var restaurants = [Restaurant]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.reloadData()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let restaurant = restaurants[indexPath.section]
    let category = restaurant.categories[indexPath.section]
    let item = category.items[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = item.name
    return cell
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return restaurants.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let restaurant = restaurants[section].categories[section]
    return restaurant.items.count
}
```

}

It will only populate each category with "shake".

Comment: Just use my suggested code in your [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825085/cannot-populate-tableview-with-just-the-name/43825165#43825165) question. Why do you mess it up??

Comment: I tried but this is my second year of programming so Im still not great at understanding tableviews. Sorry @vadian

Comment: Write code as **efficient** as possible rather than  as **short** as possible.

Comment: Ok but why is item not being separated into the proper categories @vadian

Comment: You have three levels `Restaurant` > `Category` > `Item`. In a table view you can handle only two (`Section` > `Row`). You need to add extra logic to handle also the `Item` level for example in a detail view controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143622/discussion-between-johnd337-and-vadian).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `indexPath.row` instead of `indexPath.section`.
But to answer it better, please update how you want the UI to look.
Do you want each restaurant to be a section? If yes, how do you differentiate between the different categories?

If you want nested sections, please refer this tutorial:
http://sapandiwakar.in/nested-sections-in-uitableview/

Comment: In which part be specific please @7to4

Comment: I've edited the answer requesting more info on the UI. And a screenshot of your desired output will be very handy.

Comment: Each restaurant is broken down into an array of categories which is broken down into an array of items(which is Name and numberOfCarbs). Everytime I get to the categories they load fine, but whichever category I click on "shake" shows up. I want "Fries" to show up if I click on the Chips and Fries Category

Comment: Please provide screenshots. I'm struggling to understand basic things like if you push another table view to the view controller when a tap happens, or if you have a single screen with all the info. If you give that, I can clearly say where indexPath.row has to be used :)